# No keyword with name 'Select Window' found - Got this error msg even though after adding selenium2Library as a library

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to switch to new tab using "Select Window" keyword. But getting below error msg
No keyword with name 'Select Window' found

Added selenium2Library under settings section, but still same issue

Could anyone pls help for below error msg
No keyword with name 'Select Window' found

Comment: you can try Switch Window, I think Select Window has depreciated http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Switch%20Window

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

"switch window" keyword instead. I believe select window is replaced by "switch window", switch window followed by new window title.